# How do I limit join results to pieces with a particular field value?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have a `posts` piece that has a select field `postType` with 'news' or 'event' as options. 'News' and 'Event' pieces display differently but are listed and filterable on the same index page. I'm trying to create a Featured event widget that limits the editor to choosing only posts with an 'event' postType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this when you specify your join. Just write:

```
type: 'joinByOne',
name: '_posts',
withType: 'post',
filters: {
  postType: 'news'
}
```

This works because every property of `filters` is invoked as a method of the cursor that fetches the posts, with the value given (in this case, `'news'`). The most common example you have seen is the standard advice to use the `projection` filter - it's just a cursor method, one you could chain after `find(req)` for instance.

(This will work just as well with `joinByArray` etc.)